# Dibujar solo las lineas horizontales de una tabla

Tags: css, css3

Buenas, he estado buscando porque pensaba que debía ser algo bastante fácil, pero no lo encuentro.

¿Que atributo de CSS se emplea para que solo se vean las líneas horizontales en una tabla?

[Ejemplo de una tabla que en su diseño solo hay líneas horizontales](http://www.marca.com/futbol/mas-futbol/segunda-b-grupo-iii/clasificacion.html?intcmp=MENUMIGA&s_kw=clasificacion)

Gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto:

```css
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 80%;
    }

    tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Celda1</td>
        <td>Celda2</td>
        <td>Celda3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Celda1</td>
        <td>Celda2</td>
        <td>Celda3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Celda1</td>
        <td>Celda2</td>
        <td>Celda3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```